# Массив с ключами javascript

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сделать массив который хранит данные,
знаю что можно сделать так

```
var array = {};
array.name = value;
```

Но при множественном обращении `value` не дополняется в массив, а перезаписывает, то есть больше одной строки в ячейке `array.name` создать нельзя, как сделать так, чтоб дозаписывалось в `array.name`?

Comment: ничего непонятно. Попробуй пример с данными привести, как бы ты хотел, чтобы это выглядело?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var data = { names: [] };
data.names.push("Bill");
data.names.push("John");
console.log(data);
```

> как можно сделать так, чтоб если name одинаковый - то cost
>   перезаписывался

```js
var data = { items: [] };
data.items.push({ name: "Bill", cost: 10 });
data.items.push({ name: "John", cost: 20 });

function setCostByName(anArray, aName, aCost) {
  var item = anArray.find(function(anItem){ return anItem.name == aName; });
  if (!item) {
    item = { name: aName, cost: aCost };
    anArray.push(item);
  } else {
    item.cost = aCost;
  }
}

setCostByName(data.items, "Jane", 30);
setCostByName(data.items, "Bill", 40);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: А как сделать перезапись? к примеру у меня несколько полей, `name` и `cost`, как можно сделать так, чтоб если `name` одинаковый - то `cost` перезаписывался?
И как, к примеру, получить доступ к первой строчке массива

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков Вот так - см. добавление в ответе.

Comment: отлично, сработало, но как все таки мне вывести к примеру все cost из массива? или третью строку, к примеру

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков Может, все-таки почитать про массивы? `console.log(data.items[2].cost);`

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

key - ключ

```
if(!(key in array)){
  array[key]= [];
}
array[key].push(value)
```